# Google sheet connected to google form: Run script function every time new row is added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet connected to a Google form, where users can answer three questions, which then get inserted in the sheet in columns `A`, `B` and `C`

I'm trying to set up a trigger so every time a new row is added through Form Submit, a function `foo` runs on it. I've got the following problems:

1) No matter the type of trigger I choose, I can't get the function to run, and I don't think the triggers fire correctly

2) How can I get the `Range` of the row that JUST got inserted, in the code, so I can edit its contents?

My code so far:
Trigger:
[image: screenie]

and the code for foo:

```
function foo(){
  var myRange = e.range;
  myRange.setNote("Is it working?");
  }
};
```

So far, every time a new Row is added, it doesn't have a Note, which means that either the trigger didn't fire, or there's something wrong with my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Add `e` to the function parameter: `function foo(e){Logger.log('e: ' + e)`  Also add a Logger.log() statement, and then VIEW the LOGS after the code has run.

Comment: Also, run your code from script editor once so as to see if it works and also to give it permission to access the sheet if already not done so. In the above trigger setup dialog, use the notifications link on the right to send you the error notification right way. Just until you get the code running, then set it to send it you once a day.

Comment: can anyone help me out, I could trigger a function when new record inserted through the google form

Answer (score 1):

you need to add e as a parameter of foo, and inside e you'll have all of the information inserted in the form, see [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

```
function foo(e){
      var myRange = e.range;
      myRange.setNote("Is it working?");
      Logger.log("Values from the form" + e);
}
```

If you still need the range of the row beingsubmited just call a function after onFormSubmit that gets the last row of the spreadsheet

```
var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name)
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

Comment: Nothing is happening. The new rows inserted do not have an `Is it working?` note, even after added e as a paremeter.